# How to get woodland mansion map

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I’ve been playing Minecraft for a long time, but I’ve never legitimately found a woodland mansion. I know you can get a map from trades, but I haven’t found a villager with those trades. Is there a specific type (i.e cartographer) or a percent chance for this to happen? I was also wondering if you can have a world without a woodland mansion, and if so, what the chance is that this happens. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A woodland mansion map. In order to get this you need to trade with an expert level cartographer,but there is only a chance the villager offers this trade. If you don't have one just know that they spawn in dark forest, a biomes with spruce trees and mushroom trees. If you just can't find it you can use [chunkbase.com](https://chunkbase.com) and use their woodland mansion finder. It's pretty helpful to find those mansions.

Comment: A cartographer villager will always offer a woodland explorer map at expert level (level 4)

Comment: They either trade a woodland mansion map or a ocean monument map.

Comment: They sell either an ocean monument map or woodland mansion map.

Comment: No ocean monument is level 2 (apprentice)